# Could not display Product image in an API

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I have been trying to design a rest API using Django Rest Framework for creating mobile application. I could design an API for Store list which shows store owner(merchant) information, store information, category of store and Product but product image is not displayed. Why my code is not showing product image? Could anyone please provide me an idea or advice why it is not working?

**My code**

**my models.py**

```
class Store(models.Model):
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(Merchant)
    name_of_store = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    store_off_day = MultiSelectField(choices=DAY, max_length=7, default='Sat')
    store_categories = models.ManyToManyField('StoreCategory',blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Store'


class Product(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    name_of_product = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    # categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category',blank=True)


class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/images/')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

class StoreCategory(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="store_category")
    store_category = models.CharField(choices=STORE_CATEGORIES, default='GROCERY', max_length=10)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class ProductImageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields  =   ('id','image', )

class ProductSerializers(ModelSerializer):
    image = ProductImageSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields=('id','image','name_of_product','description','price','active',)

class StoreCategorySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializers(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = StoreCategory

class StoreSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    # url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='stores_detail_api')
    store_categories = StoreCategorySerializer(many=True) 
    merchant = MerchantSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields=("id",
                # "url",
                "merchant",
                "store_categories",
                "name_of_store",
                "store_contact_number",
                "store_off_day",
                )
```

**My API**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your models.py create:

```
import os
```

Remove Product foreign key from your ProductImage model:

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/images/')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    @property
    def imagename(self):
        return str(os.path.basename(self.image.name))
```

Add image foreign key to your Product instead

```
class Product(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(ProductImage,blank=True,null=True)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    name_of_product = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    # categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category',blank=True)
```

and then in your serializers.py

```
class ProductImageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields  =   ('id','imagename', )

class ProductSerializers(ModelSerializer):
    image = ProductImageSerializer(many=False,read_only=True) #only one image used
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields=('id','image','name_of_product','description','price','active',)
```

So this way you'll  get the actual image name and location.

Comment: Did exactly as you said but still image field is not showing in an API.

Comment: You have a mistake in your foreign key reference, instead of referencing it from Product you reference it from ProductImage. See the updated code.

Comment: Yes it is working now. Thanks for your help. One last question, looking at my database model or say enitites, What do you think about my model and API design? Am i doing the right way?I just need your feedback(i am a beginner ), if you have your time not the code.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, looks good to me. The more you practice the better. You may also create separate viewset for each serializer to help you see the result.

Comment: I understand you. You really hit the nail on the head. Thanks.